# pass number into a math environment plot label

Tags: python, math, plot

```
def function(param):
    x = np.linspace(0,param,10)
    plt.plot(x,x,label = "some label that includes the parameter like" + r"$A_{param}$"
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

When I have a function like this, how can I make this labeling work?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the problem?

Comment: I want the parameter be passed into the math environment of the label, so that in my example the parameter becomes a subscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameter into the math environment of the label like this:

```
def function(param):
    x = np.linspace(0, param, 10)
    plt.plot(x, x, label="some label that includes the parameter like " + r"$A_{%d}$"%param)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

For instance, calling your function as `function(100)` would produce the following result:
[image]

BTW, `function` is a built-in name. It is better not to use python built-in names as variables' or functions' names.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
param = 5
'{{{}}}'.format(param)

> '{5}'
```